# Correctly using piped files with `subprocess` in `python`

Tags: python, subprocess, pipe

I am trying to use `subprocess` to ingest translations from `moses` open source SMT.  To test my code: The sample files that I downloaded can be found [here](http://www.statmt.org/moses/download/sample-models.tgz):

I have been trying to pipe together the various command lines that are used for a translation. The command line (from documentation) is:

```
% echo 'das ist ein kleines haus' | moses -f phrase-model/moses.ini
```

The `subprocess` that I have been working with thus far adapted from the documentation [here](https://pymotw.com/2/subprocess/):

```
import subprocess
step1 = subprocess.Popen(['echo','das ist ein kleines haus'],shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
step2 = subprocess.Popen(['/bin/moses', '-f', '/phrase-model/moses.ini'],shell=True,stdin=step1.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,)
end_of_pipe = step2.stdout
print 'Results:'
for line in end_of_pipe:
    print '\t', line.strip()
```

I am getting an error in that it does not recognize the input files in `step2` after correctly executed the bin. Thus it says that 'no configuration file was specified', although it is after the '-f' argument.

In this case, I have been reading about different libraries to execute external commands, such as `sh`, `system`, etc. but `subprocess` still seems to be the correct one for my needs, I just do not understand why it is not executing correctly each argument in my command.

Any ideas?
Also, I am working with `python2.7` in case it has an effect.

**### Progress ###**

Relying on some of the comments below, I have updated the code to and I now am receving the following error:

```
step1 = subprocess.Popen(['echo','das ist ein kleines haus'],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
step2 = subprocess.Popen(['/bin/moses', '-f', 'phrase-model/moses.ini'],shell=True,stdin=step1.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,)
```

`'Exception: util/file.cc:68 in int util::OpenReadOrThrow(const char*) threw Errno Exception because -1 == (ret = open(name,00)). No such file or directory while opening lm/europarl.srilm.gz'`

Comment: err `'/phrase-model/moses.ini'` is not `'phrase-model/moses.ini'`. So the "no configuration file was specified" is maybe a clumsy way to say "the file you specified doesn't exist"

Comment: Don't use `shell=True` when passing a list.

Comment: @chepner maybe needed for `echo` in case there's no built-in. Clearly not necessary for the second step.

Comment: I modified code according to suggestions here, i.e. I removed `shell=True` from `step2` and I put the entire definite path to the `ini` file so as to not have confusion and now the error that I receive is 'Exception: util/file.cc:68 in int util::OpenReadOrThrow(const char*) threw Errno Exception because `-1 == (ret = open(name,00)). No such file or directory while opening lm/europarl.srilm.gz ' I looked and made sure that this file was there and it is.

Comment: Your original is using a relative path; your Python is using an absolute path. Drop the leading `/`, or use a correct absolute path.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Unnecessarily relying on shell built-ins is a separate problem.

Comment: @chepner I agree with you, i was trying to run simple tests for functionality before incorporating it into larger structure.

Comment: Unless your continued use of `shell=True` is causing the new problem, the problem is that you are using the wrong working directory. (That, and `/bin/moses` could use some better error handling.)

Comment: you may not be in the directory you think you are. Use `cwd` extra option to fix execution directory.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre your hint helped me solve the problem. If you could put it as an answer I can accept.

Comment: thanks, I'll pass. This is a duplicate of "not running in the directory you think it is" mixed by "the tool you're running isn't great at error handling.